# Convert date string to date sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table `tbl` with column `cln varchar(50)`.

Data is stored in format `'January-2008'`, `February-2009`, `March-2010` etc(full `month` name)

I want to `convert` it to `date` (for `comparison`, `sort` etc).

Comment: Here my problem is `month` comes in `January`,  `February` etc...

Comment: Means u want like 01-2008? or jan-08? or something else?

Comment: date in any format is acceptable but `datatype` must be `date`

Comment: Assuming all dates you receive are in format <monthname>-<yearname>, please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below query

```
DECLARE @v varchar(20)
SET @v='January-2008'

SELECT CAST('01-'+@V as DATE)
```

Since you don't get the day data and only -, we'll add '01-' to complete the date day part.

sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f326/7

Comment: @Praveen check the sqlfiddle link I've posted in answer. Answer is still correct/

Comment: @Praveen In case you have a table say `tblname` with column `coldate` containing these values you can try `SELECT CAST('01-'+coldate as DATE) FROM tblname`

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert with Style to avoid errors in different date settings

```
DECLARE @v varchar(20)
SET @v='January-2008'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-'+@v,13)
```

Comment: Uncanny similarity is posted code. So you copied my answer and just updated the last line from `CAST` to `CONVERT`. :)

Comment: It is not that. You need to also look at the style code 13 I used